# load html page with jquery and select element from it

Tags: jquery, html, append, selector

I am having a problem with selecting an element from a previously loaded html page

if I use this code, the one before last is designated too be the last in the dom-tree
instead of the one that I just inserted

```
$("div.wrapper:last").after('<div class="wrapper"></div>'); 
    $('.wrapper:last').load('tbnote.html .pane');
    $(".pane:last").prepend("testmessage");
```

What can I do, too make it work, because I need too set the hidden field value too the primarykey value of a database table

if it is not possible, what would be an alternative to get the content in the div with the hiddenfieldvalues already set??

Thanks in advance, Richard

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.wrapper:last').load('tbnote.html .pane', function() {
   $(".pane:last").prepend("testmessage");});
```

I'm not sure what you are actually want to achieve, but a common error among developers new to jQuery is to consider that ajax functions execute instantly. On the contrary the loading of the remote html will happen asynchronously and you need to use the optional callback function.